# How to get a particular attribute of my object?

Tags: java, reflection

Let's say I have this class.

```
class People {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    /** other stuff constructor / getters / setters / etc. **/
}
```

And let's say I have this list :

```
List<People> people = Arrays.asList(new People("Mark", 21), new People("Bob",17), new People("Alex", 22));
```

Now I want to be able to get a `List` for all users of a particular attribute.

Using Java 8, I can create a method that accepts the function I want like :

```
public static <X, Y> List<Y> processElements(Iterable<X> source, Function <X, Y> mapper) {
    List<Y> l = new ArrayList<>();
    for (X p : source) 
        l.add(mapper.apply(p));
    return l;
}
```

Then I will able to perform some calls like :

```
List<String> listNames = processElements(people, p -> p.getName()); 
List<Integer> listAges = processElements(people, p -> p.getAge());
```

However this is not possible in Java 7 (I know that it exists in Guava, but I would come up with a solution only using the JDK).

This is with what I come up using reflection :

```
public static List<Object> processElements(List<People> l, String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
        Field field = People.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(People p : l){
            list.add(field.get(p));
        }
        field.setAccessible(false);
        return list;
}
```

Now I can do something like `List<Object> listNames = processElements(people, "name");` which works quite well.

But I don't feel comfortable with it :

1. I'm getting a `List<Object>`
2. Whenever I use reflection, I always feel like it exists a better implementation not using it
3. Using `field.setAccessible(true);` is not very secure

So my questions are :

1. Is it possible to do the same thing without using reflection with the JDK (not using Guava or Functional Java) ?
2. How can I get a List of String or Integer according to the type of the field I pass as parameter to my method ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a simple `Map<String, Object>` map suits your needs?

Comment: A simple for loop will do: `List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(); for (People p : list) { result.add(p.getName()); }`. What's the problem with this obvious solution? And if Guava does it, why wouldn't you be able to do it?

Comment: @JBNizet Good point for _"if Guava does"_. I would just trying to make an all-in-one function that can return me the attribute I want for all my objects in a List.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the exact same thing you were trying to do with Java 8 using an anonymous class with Java 7

```
public static <X, Y> List<Y> processElements(Iterable<X> source, Function <X, Y> mapper) {
    List<Y> l = new ArrayList<>();
    for (X p : source) 
        l.add(mapper.apply(p));
    return l;
}

List<String> listNames = processElements(people, new Function<People, String>() {
    public String apply(People person) {
        return person.getName();
    }
});
```

Comment: But he stated that he wants a solution for Java 7

Comment: @Ben This is the alternative with Java 7. Implement your own `Function` interface.

Comment: My fault, before the edit your introduction text was a bit misleading :D 1+ of course.

Comment: How couldn't I know about implementing my own Function interface.. Thanks dude, you rock !

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: No, it's not the same thing at runtime. An additional class is not created, a new instance is not created every time either, invokedynamic is used... and the whole thing is more efficient. It's actually much more than syntactic sugar.

Comment: @JB Ah, making assumptions again. I'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8, you would do it as follows:

```
List<String> names = people.stream()
    .map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.asList());
```

Your Java 8 solution works in Java 7 too as it does not use any special language construct but only the interface `Function`, which is introduced in Java 8. If you need such an interface, you can simply declare it by yourself!

```
public interface Function<T, R> {
    R apply(T t);
}
```

Comment: -1: There is no `stream()` method in List. There is also no operator like `::` in Java.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: there is one in Java 8.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux In Java 8, yes

Comment: Sorry, guys. My bad. I don't know anything about the new Java 8. Looks like Java is evolving into a super dynamic language that makes abstraction of what is going on underneath. The stream, map, collect methods are scaring me. It doesn't feels "pure" anymore.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux A lot of influence from functional programming languages.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Every time I play with Java 8, I feel depressed when going back to Java 7. The functional idioms are sooo useful and clean. You'll probably get used to it, and even appreciate them.

Comment: The streaming API makes perfectly sense with lambda expressions. I've tried without (using anonymous inner classes), and it made me sick...

Comment: I've the felt like Java 8 is very influencated by Scala